# On the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a closed bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

When we speak of the $\sigma$-algebra of the Borel sets in the bounded closed interval $[0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}$, we should consider the interval $[0,1]$ as a topological space. My doubt at this point is the following: When it is not mentioned any specific topology on $[0,1]$, do we consider $[0,1]$ as the topological subspace of $(\mathbb{R}, d_{\mathbb{R}})$, where $d_{\mathbb{R}}$ is the usual Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}$, or, do we consider $[0,1]$ as a topological space $([0,1], d_{\mathbb{R}}|_{[0,1]\times [0,1]})$, where  $d_{\mathbb{R}}|_{[0,1]\times [0,1]}$ is the restriction of $d_{\mathbb{R}}$ to $[0,1]\times [0,1]$. The confusion arises for me, for example, if $\alpha\in (0,1)$ then, while the interval
$[0,\alpha)=(-1,\alpha)\bigcap[0,1]$ is an open subset of $[0,1]$ with respect to the subspace topology on $[0,1]$, but it is not open in $([0,1], d_{\mathbb{R}}|_{[0,1]\times [0,1]})$. Am I right? Or, are these two topologies equivalent on $[0,1]$? Well, I am so confused!

Comment: The two topologies are the same, and they generate the same $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any set $A \subset \mathbb R$ the topology generated by the restriction of the usual metric to $A$ and the subspace topology of $A$ (consisting of the sets $A \cap U$ where $U$ is open in $\mathbb R$) are one and the same.

Comment: Can you please show that the topology generated by the restriction is stronger than the subspace topology on the set $A$?

Comment: @serenus Let $U$ be open in $\mathbb R$ and $x \in U\cap A$. We have to show that $B_{d_A}(x,r) \subset U\cap A$ $\cdots$ (1) for some $r>0$ where $d_A$ is the restriction of the usual metric $d$ on $\mathbb R$ to $A$. There is an open ball $B(x,r)$ in $\mathbb R$ which is contained in $U$ and this same $r$ gives (1)..

Comment: Why the open ball $B(x,r)$ is contained in $A$?

Comment: @serenus I it is not contained in $A$. But the ball with center $x$ and radius $r$ in $A$ (for the restriction of the metric to $A$) is $B(x,r) \cap A$ which is contained in $A$.

Comment: So, you take $B_{d_A}(x,r)$ as the intersection $B(x,r)\cap A$.

Comment: @serenus Yes, it is the set of points in $A$ which are at distance less then $r$ from $x$.